# What are the advantages of using demand systems estimation? How is this different from individual demand estimation for product?

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics, mathematical-economics, demand, demand-system-estimation

I don't understand how is demand systems estimation is different from simple demand equation estimation. What's the best resource for getting a history line of demand systems?

Comment: The seminal work is probably [Deaton and Muellbauer](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/economics-and-consumer-behavior/75DEDED955947555732A39E38D87D0EA). Its from 1980, so a bit dated, but still a great work if you want a good introduction to demand and demand system estimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One advantage of considering demand systems is that more data is available for identifying the degree of income effects and substition between commodities. A second advantage is the possibility to impose and test microeconomic restrictions (which are between equations). An introduction to the estimation of demand systems with an historical perspective is provided by:
Berndt, E. R., 1991, *The Practice of Econometrics: classic and contemporary*, Addison Wesley.
More recent treatments are available in most econometric textbooks.